# .htaccess auto_prepend_file if url contains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to auto include a global.php file using htaccess. Right now I have

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/local/directory/global.php"
```

which works perfect. The problem is, I run this site both on a local server for development, and a remote web server for the live site. So obviously the /local/directory/ path is going to be variable based on whether I'm on mysite.com or mysite.local.

Is there a way to say if url contains mysite.local, include this file; otherwise include this file, inside the htaccess?

Comment: Why not just have different `.htaccess` files in place on localhost and in production?

Comment: Or, since the `include_path` settings is used, why not give a _relative_ path to the `auto_prepend_file` instead of an absolute one …?

Comment: Yes it would work if I had two separate .htaccess files, and that's my go-to solution if there is no other solution.. but I'd rather not do that.

Comment: Also, yes I could do a relative path; but then that requires me to have a different .htaccess in every subfolder.

Comment: No, a relative path would not require different `.htaccess` files for subdirectories, if the `include_path` is set so that the file can be found using the directories included in the `include_path` …

Comment: Are you sure about that? I tried it before and got not found errors in my php log when I was inside mysite.com/subdir/home, yet no errors when I was on mysite.com/home. As soon as I made it the full path the errors stopped.

Comment: Then your `include_path` is not set so that the file can be found using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Apache >= 2.4 to make this really conditional.

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'mysite.local'">
    # ...
</If>
<Else>
    # ...
</Else>
```

For earlier versions, this is only possible by adding a -D option to the startup command line (-DLOCAL below), then:

```
<IfDefine LOCAL>
    # ...
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !LOCAL>
    # ...
</IfDefine>
```

(for Apache >= 2.4, see also the Define directive - same effect as adding a -D argument)

Comment: This is the exact solution I was hoping to find. However, my live server is running 2.2.22 so it unfortunately won't work for me. But great solution if you're running 2.4+!

Answer (score 0):

use site custodia settings
For lightpd go in php.ini and alocat the USD of .user.ini
For Apache must set the allowOveride All for YouTube site directori and plase in that directori a .htaccess file containing " php_value autoprepend_file path"